# Add columns to an existing source of data

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, nested-if

I would like to **add several columns to an existing source of data displayed in a sheet**. But as a data source, the number of rows can increase. I don't want to update the sheet once it is set up, it should be automatic. In those new columns, I would like formulas.

Please find below the result expected.

- in blue, columns from data source
- in red, my new columns with a formula

[image]

**How can I do ?**

Thank for you help

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with included example of desired output

Comment: Thank for your reply. First sheet, data source. Second one is made with the first one but with additional formula. The "difficulty" is the data source will become bigger and I don't want to update manually the second sheet every time.

I put here the GSheet of what I expect :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15GFUHIL2o6wTbRJUgicNVcCTrHvr3U_1CffmZ2hAUpU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in E1:

```
={"new col 1"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="";;IF((ISNUMBER(C2:C))*(C2:C>=2); 1; 0)))}
```

use in F1:

```
={"new col 2"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D="";;IF((ISNUMBER(D2:D))*(D2:D>=2); 10; 0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll test tomorrow. Thank you for your reply !

Comment: It works, you're awesome, even if don't understand everything and especially why the second parameter is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a custom function and to personalize it with another project, it doesn't work...

In this simple case, it works. If not empty, it returns G cells in uppercase :

```
={"Feature"; ARRAYFORMULA(SI(G2:G="";;IF((NOT(ISEMPTY(G2:G))); UPPERCASE(G2:G); "-")))}
```

In other case with a custom function, not. It is named "getFeature"

```
={"Feature"; ARRAYFORMULA(SI(G2:G="";;IF((NOT(ISEMPTY(G2:G))); getFeature(G2:G); "-")))}
```

[image: screenshot]

When I use it in a classic way, my function works : =getFeature(G7)

Here my custom function :

```
function getFeature(searchString)  {

  if (searchString === "")  {
    return ""
  }

  var sFeature = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("raw feature")
  var rFeatureCol = sFeature.getRange(2, 1, sFeature.getLastRow(), 1)
  
  array = searchString.split(";")

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    try  {
      var textFinder = rFeatureCol.createTextFinder(array[i])
      var search_row = textFinder.findNext().getValue()
      return array[i]
    }
    catch {
      // erreur détectée
    }
  }

  return ""
}
```